# Finding whether stream intersection is non-empty

Tags: java, algorithm, java-8, java-stream

Obtaining an intersection of two streams, or finding whether their intersection is empty or not is generally not possible in Java, since streams can only be used once, and the generic solution has a [image: O(m*n)] complexity.

If we don't know anything about the nature of the underlying supplier, we can get away with at most one stream and one collection:

```
<T> boolean intersects(final Stream<T> c1, final Collection<T> c2) {
    return c1.filter(c2::contains).findAny().isPresent();
}
```

Still, what if both our suppliers represent *ordered* collections sorted using the same comparator (in the most simple case, two `TreeSet`s of `Comparable`s)? In this case, solution will have *linear* complexity (or, more precise, [image: O(m*n)], see [this](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/78411/106244) answer).

Now the question: can the above *linear* solution be implemented using *only* Stream API (i. e. using two streams as the input)?

Comment: Are you asking if you can implement the linear solution if the data in the streams is ordered?

Comment: Iterative solutions and streams don’t fit together, so the best thing you can do, is invoke `iterator()` on the streams and go on.

Comment: @JimMischel Yes, exactly

Comment: @Holger Thought of that, too. It looks like the `Stream` interface providing the `iterator()` method is an indirect evidence that iterators provide more flexibility over streams.

Comment: It only acknowledges the fact that you can’t do everything that way. Such iterative algorithms are not the scope of the Stream API.

Comment: The closest built-in Java 8 feature I can find is [`Collections.disjoint(Collection, Collection)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#disjoint-java.util.Collection-java.util.Collection-), which returns false if any values are in common, but it doesn't accept streams. Each would have to be converted into a `Collection` of some kind first.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can just collect the second Stream into a `Set` and ask whether any element of the first Stream is contained in this set:

```
<T> boolean intersects(final Stream<T> c1, final Stream<T> c2) {
    return c1.anyMatch(c2.collect(Collectors.toSet())::contains);
}
```

Making the set out of `c1` is linear in terms of the number of elements in it, and `contains` is a constant-time operation.

Comment: Thanks, this is a good solution and it anwers the question, as no limitations as per memory footprint have been set. Still, the original iterative solution (advancing either of the two iterators) doesn't require any extra memory while your stream-based one does. Is it possible to solve the same task in linear time w/o introducing any new collections?

Comment: @Bass short answer: no.  Long answer: noooooo.  Not without converting the streams back to iterators, basically.

Comment: @Bass And the issue with having an iterator is that you can't "peek" an element easily. You need to consume it with `next()`, so it is a lot more difficult to only advance one of the two iterators.